# Is an RDBS a good solution for storing documents over really long periods of time (years)?

Tags: mysql, document, archive, rdbms

I was wondering is `MySQL` a solution for archiving (securely) documents for long periods of times (decades)?
Is anything other than an RDBMS a standard approach to this?
I am trying to see if my simple understanding of storing a document e.g. as a BLOB in a table is not the correct/standard approach for archiving documents

Comment: If you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail. The approach I'd suggest is Amazon S3 or Amazon Glacier.

Comment: You know that there's [a class of products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_management_system) specifically designed for that kind of work?

Comment: It's all about regularly testing your restore/recovery method, though you may wish to investigate whether you need to meet certain standards (ISO).

Comment: Usability is another aspect.  If these are documents that are just getting vaulted and likely won't need to be retrieved again any time in the near future, database storage may be okay.  If these documents might need to get accessed occasionally, adding a SQL layer between the user and the document might not be the best thing to do......

Comment: @MarcusAdams:ISO?Like what?

Comment: @fvu:But I don't need to modify etc. Only to store retrieve

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is likely going to get flagged down as being primarily opinion based, I'd say yes it's a solid way to store and retrieve documents (or any form of data for that matter!) long term.  Of course, there's other factors to this too, for example, how's the data redundancy on the system that holds the database?  Are there any backups of it offsite, etc.  Really though, provided you're careful, you can store the documents as plain files in a folder as long as you're mirroring them, and backing them up appropriately.

For what it's worth, we do just that at my work.  We have a plain folder with a couple million (literally) documents stored in it, and we retrieve them from a network share....it works fine, and we have it's contents mirrored off a couple other places too, for disaster recovery purposes.  Database storage would be doable, however it's easier to access the documents from outside applications directly via a fileshare path as opposed to database retrieval.  This way also allows someone (with the correct permissions to access the folder directly anyways) to pick and choose what files they need without having to query against a database on each separate file.